# Are Hololens VR ready?

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, hololens

The question is already quite direct and short:

> Can the Hololens be used as a virtual reality glasses?

Sorry beforehand if the question is clear for those who have tried them out, but I had not yet the chance.

From what I read I know that they have been designed to be a very good **augmented reality** tool. This approach is clear for everybody.

Just thinking that may be applications where you simply don't want the user to have any spatial contact with the reality for some moments, or others where you want the user to forget in the complete experience about were s-he is, then a complete environment should be shown as we are used to with the **virtual reality** glasses.

How are the Hololens ready for this? I think there are two key sub-questions that may be answered for this:

How solid are the holograms?

Does the screen where holograms can be placed covers the complete view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The holograms quality is defined by the following [specs](https://www.windowscentral.com/hololens-hardware-specs): 
 - Holographic Resolution: 2.3M total [light points](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/92/whats-a-light-point) 
 - Holographic Density: 2.5k light points per radian 
It is worth to say that Microsoft holograms disappear under a certain distance indicated [here](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3039822/consumer-electronics/we-found-7-critical-hololens-details-that-microsoft-hid-inside-its-developer-docs.html) in 0.85m

Personal note: in the past I worked also on Google Project Tango and I can tell you from these personal experiences that the stability of Microsoft holograms is absolutely superior. Also, the holograms are kept once the device is turned off, so if you place something and you reboot the device you will find them again where you left them, without the need to restart from scratch

2) Absolutely not: "[The field of view] amounts to the size of a monitor in front of you – equivalent to 15 inches" as stated [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/wearables/this-is-how-microsoft-s-hololens-will-address-its-biggest-flaw-1322596). And it will not be addressed as reported also [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2937806/the-hololens-field-of-view-wont-be-getting-any-bigger-says-microsoft-exec.html). So if the holograms size exceeds this space they will be shown partially [i.e. cut]. Moreover the surrounding environment is always visible because the device purpose is interacting with the real environment adding another layer on top

Answer (score 3):

As others already pointed out, this is a solid **No** due to the limited viewing window.

Apart from that, the current hardware capabilities of the Hololens is not capable of providing a full immersive experience. You can check the specifications [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/22/microsoft_hololens_hpu/).

As of now, when the environment is populated with more than a few holograms (depends on the triangle count of each hologram) the device's fps count drops and a certain lag is visible. I'm sure more processing power would be added to the device in future versions, but as of right now, with the current power of the device, I seriously doubt its capabilities to populate an entire environment to give a fully immersive experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution Ashan. I suspected already this drop in case of many holograms in the scene. On the other hand if no spacial recognition has to be done, the device could focus on full immersive experience. But this cannot be accomplished as you say, solid No, because of its window size (window always in front where holograms can be shown)... this is for me even a counterpart for its original purpose: augmented reality.

Comment: You're quite right, the biggest limitation I experienced in the hololens is its view port size. Due to that, specially when inspecting holograms closer to you, many parts gets cropped out. But if you are viewing holograms from a sufficient distance away when all the holograms easily fit inside the view port, the limitation becomes much less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Hololens is not intended to be a VR rig, there is no complete immersion that I am aware of, yes you can have solid holograms, but you can always see the real world.

Comment: Does the screen covers the complete view?

Comment: absolutely not: "[It] amounts to the size of a monitor in front of you – equivalent to 15 inches" as stated [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/wearables/this-is-how-microsoft-s-hololens-will-address-its-biggest-flaw-1322596) And it will not be addressed as reported also [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2937806/the-hololens-field-of-view-wont-be-getting-any-bigger-says-microsoft-exec.html)

Comment: @Antonino thanks for the links! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @juagicre happy to have been helpful ;)

Comment: @Antonino post the answer and I'll give it as valid :) (even I wrote already a resume of my conclusion)

Answer (score 1):

VR is related with substituting the real world that is why VR goggles are always blind. HoloLens are type of see-through so you can see the hologram and the real world. There are created for augmented reality where you augment the real world. That is why you can't use HoloLens for VR purpous

Comment: Differences are clear to me. Having the Hololens a much better technology would make it a VR tool as well.

Comment: @juagicre what do you mean by "better technology would make it a VR tool as well" ? THe fact that this is AR is not caused by limitation of the technology. Those are two different things. Like smartphone and tablet. They look the same, they do simillar things but they are not the same thing, not cause smartphone is limited by technology but because it was designed to do something else

Comment: thanks for clarification, but definition of AR and VR are clear. I know my sentence is quite simplistic: "better technology". I mean in case of having a complete screen on your view would allow to make it VR-able, no contact with the reality. One tool for two technologies, for two different approaches, I know, but as we have cameras on our mobiles, why not merging as well VR and AR? (note here that also VR could add the AR possibility with cameras, infrared detectors, space mapping...) I know those are too early times for such a suggestion, but before I did my question I had no idea...

Comment: @juagicre now I see. You're talking about "video see through". Yes with this kind of goggles you can manage to create VR and AR soft on one device BUT this is not the goal of AR. VST are not very natural. You're losing the depth of the things that you see. They are often used in AR projects because they are relatively cheep (when you compare it to true AR goggles). HoloLens were created in different purpose that is why they are not a VSF type

Answer (score 0):

Actually my initial question is: can the Hololens be used AS WELL for VR applications?

**No** is the answer because of its small window (equivalent to 15'' screen) where the holograms can be placed to.

I am sure this will evolve sooner or later in order to improve the AR experience. As soon as the screen does not cover toe complete view VR won't be possible with the Hololens.

Answer (score 0):

The small FOV is a problem for total immersion, but there is an app for HoloLens called HoloTour, which is VR (with a few AR scenes in the beginning). In the game, the user can travel to Rome and Peru. While you can still see through the holograms, in my personal experience, people playing it will really get into it and will forget about the limitations. After a scene or two, they feel immersed. So while it certainly isn't as good at VR as a machine designed for that, it is capable, and it is still typically enjoyable to the users. There are quite a few measures to prevent nausea in the users (I can use mine for hours at a time with no problem) so I would actually prefer it to poorer VR implementations, such as a GearVR (which made me sick after 10 minutes of use!). Surely a larger FOV is in the works, so this will be less of a limitation in future releases.

Comment: Just thought I'd add a more optimistic answer! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for bringing here your experience!